# Error in try catch while converting VC6 to VS2008

Tags: c++, windows, exception, mfc, cexception

When I opened a VC6 project in VS2008 and tried building it , initially I got the error:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'iostream.h': No such file or directory
>
> error C2259: 'CException' : cannot instantiate abstract class
>
> error BK1506 : cannot open file '.\Debug\SClientDlg.sbr': No such file or directory    BSCMAKE SClient

Now I have changed `#include"iostream.h"` to `#include"iostream"`  and now getting 7errors ( as I have used  try and catch 7 places) saying:

> error C2259: 'CException' : cannot instantiate abstract class

Below is the snippet from that code:

```
void SClientDlg::ProcessDomainName(int *m_pDlg,char* strDomainName,int iLen)
{
    try
    {
    //Do Something
    
    }
    catch(CException ex)
    {
        printf("Exception: %d",GetLastError()); 
    }
   
    
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You likely need to do this:

```
catch(CException& ex) // const& might be better
```

Since `CException` is abstract, you cannot instantiate it, but you can reference a non-abstract object that derives from it.

Comment: Solved the error, but curious to know why it was not throwing any error in VC6

Comment: @Subhen: Not a clue. :) Probably had the same semantics, but VC6 was pre-standard and I haven't put much effort into learning it.